# SQL Create A New Table off Of Query Results , in one Query

Tags: sql

Below is my attempt to create a table from a query, having a little trouble getting the insert into statement to work, the rest of the query works great, just cannot get my return results into a new table any idea how to ?

```
    CREATE TABLE test (
        a varchar(255),
        b varchar(255),

    )
--I assume the above is wrong , not sure why-- 

  Insert into test (a, b)
    select (B , Cor)
    from 
    (
      --below works great---
      Select B,
             CASE
               WHEN B = 't' THEN 'test' 
               WHEN B = '-' THEN 'NULL'

               WHEN B = 'Choos' THEN 'NULL'

               WHEN B = 'Se Co' THEN 'S'

               --
               WHEN B LIKE 'Y%' THEN 'di'
               WHEN B LIKE 'T%' THEN 'Ten'
               --
               ELSE B

           END AS Cor
    FROM
      (SELECT WON AS B
       FROM ma
       UNION SELECT C
       FROM ma )
    Order By B )
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: In standard SQL, this is done using `create table test as select ....` - but you need to remove the completely wrong parentheses around the column list in the select part.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are suspicious:

```
Insert into test (a, b)
    select (B, Cor)
-----------^
```

Some databases might interpret this as a single tuple (struct or record) with two fields.  Some will generate an error.  Basically, you want to drop the parens:

```
Insert into test (a, b)
    select B, Cor
    . . .
```

Comment: @pes04: you need to end each statement with `;` the way you have written it, it is assumed to be one big statement.